# Mutt message: "Alarm Clock"

Tags: sendmail, mutt

short version: I'm trying to send mail with Mutt. It fails and says "Alarm clock". What does that mean, how do I fix it?

long version: I have an ubuntu server running [tiny tiny rss](https://tt-rss.org/). It sends daily email digests using php's mail() function. I want that to work. I have a domain with google apps, so I want mail to be sent from vassago@adamrgrey.com. I tried postfix and sendmail, but I failed to configure them properly (and I think since they're MTAs they're overkill anyway). I hear (read: hope) that mutt can be used to replace sendmail for php's purposes. So to the end of sending mail from mutt, I made a .muttrc for my own gmail account, and sending worked fine. So I suspect mutt is installed correctly. However, when I change my configuration to work for my domain name, it doesn't work. here's my new .muttrc:

```
set from = "vassago@adamrgrey.com"
set realname = "vassago"
set imap_user = "vassago@adamrgrey.com"
set imap_pass = <password>
set smtp_url="smtp://vassago@mail.adamrgrey.com:587/"
set smtp_pass=<password>
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed ="+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set header_cache = ~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir =~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file =~/.mutt/certificates
set move = no
set imap_keepalive = 900
```

if I just run mutt, I can see the emails show up. I've tried deleting the lines with smtp_url and smtp_pass, but that didn't work either. With this configuration, I run

```
echo "hi again" | mutt -s "test03 from mutt" <my email address>
```

some time passes, "Alarm clock" prints, and the program returns, mail ostensibly not sent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was smtp_url. I changed the line:

```
set smtp_url="smtp://vassago@adamrgrey.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
```

now it works. I still have no idea what "Alarm clock" means.

Comment: I have my smtp_url exactly like that (smtp://user@domain.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/), smtp_pass has the correct password, and I still get the same message "Alarm clock". No explanations. Can anyone explain what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, "Alarm clock" is a mutt error message relating to timeout.

Lately, I have been plagued with that cutesey "Alarm clock" error indication while trying to debug my mutt ".muttrc" file. The main problem turned out to be a combination of the "set smtp_url" parameter and msmtp's connect_timeout parameter. Local internet service is spotty at best, and thus the timeout problems.

MAIN PROBLEM:
When I sent a multi-line text file to mutt via the command line:
    cat report.out | mutt -s "Summary" "myemailacct@gmail.com"
mutt repeatedly blew up with the cryptic message
    Alarm clock
I wasted considerable time chasing the problem within mutt. There WAS one problem, but the main culprit was in .msmtprc instead. Fix it first.

MSMTP BACKGROUND: But first, some background. I'm running msmtp, and thought that it was working fine: for example, the cmd line
    cat report.out | msmtp -a default myemailacct@gmail.com
did as expected, sending the last line of the file without a subject.

Here is a copy of .msmtprc. I have included the trick to enable secure smtps:

## ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
account gmail
host smtp.gmail.com          
port 465                  
from "myemailacct@gmail.com"   
tls on                       
#tls_starttls on              
# If you get a "server sent empty reply" error, add the following line:
    tls_starttls off
# This allows msmtp to use SSL/TLS (port 465) in place of STARTTLS (port 587)
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
auth on                     
user "myemailacct"       
password "mypassword"       
logfile ~/.msmtp.log

# Set a default account
account default : gmail
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------

Typing in 
    msmtp --serverinfo
gives all sorts of information, such as (showing top two lines only):
    SMTP server at smtp.gmail.com (qo-in-f109.1e100.net [173.194.66.109]), port 465:
            smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w44sm25263807qta.4 - gsmtp
which demonstrates that smtps is configured correctly (so far). If it were not configured correctly, you would get the following:
    msmtp: the server sent an empty reply
    msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /home/owner/.msmtprc)

After tinkering with msmtp.rc I resumed testing, jumping back and forth between msmtp and mutt. The program occasionally worked, but not reproduceably. In retrospect, this should have suggested a timeout problem. (I'll omit lots of grief here.) Let's cut to the chase and add the following line to .msmtprc (which fixed the problem):
    set connect_timeout = 300
Be sure to test any changes with 
    msmtp --serverinfo
before plowing ahead. The msmtp server MUST work before you can straighten out mutt.

MUTT PROBLEM/SOLUTION: Next, I made a correction to .muttrc by including the host name in the smtp_url argument. I commented out:
    # set hostname=gmail.com
and inserted the hostname into the url:
    set smtp_url = "smtps://myemailacct@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465

RESULTS: Once I added the .msmtprc timeout line and fixed the .muttrc host_name problem mentioned above, it all ran fine, consistently albeit slowly. The slowness is due to a lousy internet connection. There are two large hospitals which do major data dumps twice a day, tying up the trunk. Plus, due to lousy infrastructure out here in the suburbs, seems like every time a cloud goes over the connection goes down. Please write your senators and congressman in favor of internet neutrality.

Comment: "_Actually, "Alarm clock" is a mutt error message relating to timeout._" This helped me, thanks. I had a typo in my muttrc as well.